# how to get data from moble app into web app

Tags: mobile, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have designed my web app using mvc and designed the web api's to send the data to the mobile app in the form of json. I want to understand what to do, if a user registered on the mobile app,I (as the server side) should be able to get this data and save it into my database (again server side) so that the user can access from web app as well with the same credentials.how could that happen? I mean should I design a web api to receive data from the mobile party?I hope my question is not dump or silly or asked wrong because I'm trying to learn and understand. I really would like some explanation.

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question, do you want to know the right way for authentication between your mobile app and back-end api or you want to know how to return the data? Not clear question :(

Comment: I want to understand how I get the registration data from the mobile app as a server side to save these data into my database.this is my project https://github.com/lama512/MVC5-DB-first-entity-framework I now want to get data from the mobile side (username-password-email) how can I achieve that?

Comment: I've created something similar using token based authentication for the mobile app to be allowed to post data - using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: I dont want authentication, I'm assuming the parametrs I want to get are in the cloud I only want to know how can I get these parametrs into my database